# C# SQL export formatting

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having trouble setting up this code to export the text in the format that I'd like, any tips would be great.

Scenario:  I have a listBox being populated from an SQL query.  That listBox has a button to populate listBox2.  The columns name are whatever columns picked from the listbox1, and the data is the corresponding data.  I was able to set this format up in a dataset, but I had to change it do to the massive databases.

I'm having trouble formatting my dataset code into this stream code. I need to export in the following format.

```
Column name|Column name|Column name|Column name|Column name|Column name|
```

Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data|Data

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=" + security);
con.Open();
using (FileStream strm = new FileStream(exportfile, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strm))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            writer.Write(rdr[0].ToString() + "|" + rdr[1].ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is the dataset code which exports perfectly:

```
DataTable tbltarget = dataset.Tables[0];
string output_text =
    tbltarget.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList()
    .Select(col => col.ColumnName)
    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + "|" + next) + "\r\n"
    +
    tbltarget.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
    .Select(row => row.ItemArray.Aggregate((current, next) => current.ToString() + "|" + next.ToString().Replace("\n", "")))
    .Cast<string>().Aggregate((current, next) => current + "\r\n" + next);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\InPrep\" + textBox1.Text + "\\CI\\cnr.txt", output_text);
```

Updated code:

```
using (FileStream strm = new FileStream(exportfile, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strm))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            writer.Write((i==0?"":"|") + reader.GetName(i));
        writer.Write("\n");
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i =0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            writer.Write((i==0?"":"|") + reader[i].ToString().Replace(@"<me> ", string.Empty).Replace(@" </me>|", "").Replace(@" </me>", ";").Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ') + "|");
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking a question here? You are saying the second code fragmetn works perfectely, so what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is i cant get the top code to export in the same format the bottom code is in.  I'm too new to understand how to make the top code export the output_text because i was able to set the output_text to a dataset to the .Columns.Cast and .Rows.Cast doesnt work.

Comment: the bottom code does everything in one big chunk and runs out of memory (the SQL table is about 3 million rows).  The above code addresses memory issue, but the bottom code exports correctly, how do i get them to work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you process information from the reader. Replace the `Console.Write*` with `Stream.Write*` for your code. Try this,

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//Print the column names.
for(int i=0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    Console.Write((i==0?"":"|") + reader.GetName(i));
Console.WriteLine();

//Process each record, note that reader.Read returns one record at a time.
while(reader.Read())
{
    for(int i=0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        Console.Write((i==0?"":"|") + reader[i].ToString().Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\n', ' '));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: This doesnt handle the multientry at the end of the line well.    BDc|EDc|DDate|DType|DTitle|Autr|cip|  produces:  
972328|972335|070305|<me> MS </me>|SUCAL INV MIS:|<me> VVM32792 </me>
<me> XO WEL </swme>||

the <me> is multi entry
this produced 2 extra lines

Comment: I hope by <me> you mean line feeds. You could do this by replacing \r \n with a space. I've changed the code slightly to implement this, try it out

Comment: <me> actually stands for multientry in which a 3rd party program adds these to process its internal multientry display

Comment: It works great, now if it didnt add an extra "|" at the end of each line it would be perfect!

Comment: Actually i lied, i cant get it to stop writing out an "| at the end of the line.

Comment: ok, changed again to remove the final |, note the addition of (i==0?"":"|") when doing the stream.write

Comment: The code also exports the header row and first row together...

Thanks in advance i know this is so close

Comment: He's got you close enough. You should be able to handle string manipulation from here.

Comment: I appricate all the help.  Why does the header row exclude the last "|" and the rows don't though?

Comment: you forgot to remove the final + "|" when writing the fields :)